# Upgrading MongoDB from 3.6 to 4.4

Tags: upgrade, mongodb

I need to upgrade my MongoDB installation from its current incarnation of 3.6.8 to 4.4.

If I understand the documentation correctly, this has to be done in stages, from 3.6 to 4.0, then from 4.0 to 4.2, and then, finally, to 4.4.

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

First, do I need to dump the databases and restore them each time or can I just upgrade the server (after running a backup of the database directory, of course)?

Second, and probably most important, where do I find the packages for the intermediate versions>  All I can find is the current, 4.4, edition, so perhaps I'm not looking in the right place.

If it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to punt on this one, back up everything, scrub the installation, and install 4.4.

As of this writing, all seems to be working.

I hate it when the obvious answer is not only staring me in the face but jumping up and down and screaming "You idiot, you IDIOT."